# как распарсить json если в нём нет name

Tags: c#, json

Как распарсить такой json?

```json
[
    [
        1633471200000,
        "51742.81000000",
        "51792.39000000",
        "51348.00000000",
        "51375.88000000",
        "509.50068000",
        1633474799999,
        "26241395.67083850",
        19649,
        "212.80314000",
        "10960443.63736740",
        "0"
    ],
    [
        1633474800000,
        "51375.87000000",
        "51640.00000000",
        "51370.62000000",
        "51493.60000000",
        "271.34142000",
        1633478399999,
        "13983419.71127710",
        12823,
        "152.68179000",
        "7868298.05249060",
        "0"
    ],
    [
        1633478400000,
        "51498.50000000",
        "51524.99000000",
        "51224.46000000",
        "51345.81000000",
        "432.97785000",
        1633481999999,
        "22229668.86963980",
        17184,
        "215.08740000",
        "11043762.36694210",
        "0"
    ]
]
```

С таким проблем нет

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1115817744,
        "price": "61990.25000000",
        "qty": "0.00255000",
        "quoteQty": "158.07513750",
        "time": 1635282032007,
        "isBuyerMaker": true,
        "isBestMatch": true
    },
    {
        "id": 1115817745,
        "price": "61990.26000000",
        "qty": "0.00805000",
        "quoteQty": "499.02159300",
        "time": 1635282032142,
        "isBuyerMaker": false,
        "isBestMatch": true
    },
    {
        "id": 1115817746,
        "price": "61990.26000000",
        "qty": "0.00391000",
        "quoteQty": "242.38191660",
        "time": 1635282032196,
        "isBuyerMaker": false,
        "isBestMatch": true
    }
]
```

Для первого json есть класс

```cs
public class Candle
{
    public List<object> MyArray { get; set; }
}
```

Для второго

```cs
public class RecentTradesList
{
    public Int64 id    { get; set; }
    public string price { get; set; }
    public string qty   { get; set; }
    public string quoteQty { get; set; }
    public Int64  time     { get; set; }
    public bool isBuyerMaker { get; set; }
    public bool isBestMatch  { get; set; }
}
```

Второй json без проблем разбираю с помощью

```
var _data = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<RecentTradesList[]>(_comand + _body);
```

А первый не могу с помощью

```
var _data = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<Candle[]>(_comand + _body);
```

Я понимаю что это из за того что нету name в json но как быть в таком случае?

upd:

```
    public class Root
    {
        public List<List<object>> MyArray { get; set; }
    }

respon = await client.GetAsync(_comand + _body);
Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(respon.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

Содержимое respon.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result

> [[1633471200000,"51742.81000000","51792.39000000","51348.00000000","51375.88000000","509.50068000",1633474799999,"26241395.67083850",19649,"212.80314000","10960443.63736740","0"],[1633474800000,"51375.87000000","51640.00000000","51370.62000000","51493.60000000","271.34142000",1633478399999,"13983419.71127710",12823,"152.68179000","7868298.05249060","0"],[1633478400000,"51498.50000000","51524.99000000","51224.46000000","51345.81000000","432.97785000",1633481999999,"22229668.86963980",17184,"215.08740000","11043762.36694210","0"]]

Ошибка:

> {"Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'binance.classes.api+Root' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '', line 1, position 1."}

Решение:
Помогло

```
var myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<object>>>(respon.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

Comment: Это массив массивов. `object[][]` или `List<List<object>>`. / В Visual Studio есть пункт меню: Edit > Paste Special > Paste Json As Classes

Comment: `Candle[]` -> `double[][]`. Если используется `System.Text.Json`, то заставьте этого бездарного упрямца самостоятельно из строки в число переводить, указав в его настройках `NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString`.

Comment: "Это массив массивов. object[][] или List<List<object>>" - не помогло

Comment: `не помогло` - скажите хоть как вы поняли, что не помогло, ошибка какая? или что?

Comment: public class Candle
        {
            public List<List<object>> MyArray { get; set; }
        } - сделал так, ошибка таже самая что не может распарсить

Comment: @Sergey вы можете раскрыть секрет и показать текст ошибки и трассировку стека? Отредактируйте вопрос. Если вам нужна помощь с этим, конечно.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Зачем вы используете Newtonsoft.Json в .NET 5? Используйте System.Text.Json. А вообще вот так должно быть `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<object>>>(...)` ну или хотя-бы `client.GetFromJsonAsync` как в первом примере показано. А в ошибке явно написано, в чем проблема, у вас массив `[]`, а вы пытаетесь десереализовать это в объект `{ "MyArray": [] }`.

Comment: Помогло var myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<List<object>>>(respon.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result); Большое спасибо!

Comment: если нужна производительность, то лучше массив, а не список `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<object[][]>(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())`. И избегайте использования `.Result` нет никакой гарантии, что `ReadAsStringAsync` всегда завершится синхронно, и вы не словите дедлок. Но лучше именно вот так `var result = await client.ReadAsJsonAsync<object[][]>(url)` и удалить Newtonsoft.Json из проекта.

Comment: Кстати в System.Text.Json выглядело бы вот так `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<object[][]>(await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())`

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: Забавно наблюдать, как решение, полученное в первых двух комментариях, размусоливается на целую поэму) А мой коммент походу и вовсе проигнорировали, ведь прямым текстом написал, что заменить и на что. Также внимательно посмотрите на свои данные, вы там видите что-либо кроме чисел? Я - нет. Так почему это `object`? И опять же, сказал, что надо сделать чтоб заработало... Если вам этого мало, то [вот пример](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qJU0sr). А, ну и почему от `GetFromJsonAsync` отказались я тоже особо не понял... Собственно, странно это все тут пошло.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
public class Root
{
    public List<List<object>> MyArray { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Это код думаю с сайта https://json2csharp.com/ . Он бесполезен.

Comment: @Sergey подозреваю, что это не код бесполезен, он как раз нормальный а проблема в другом. А вот в чем именно - вы качественно скрываете.

Comment: Отредактировал вопрос

Comment: Можете отредактировать ответ, решение в комментах выше.